# Step Over throws exception, but Step Into not Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2019

I am making a unity game and have one strange situation, which I will try to explain.
Here is my UserCreator class in which I want to return nativeCountry from another class (MySQLCountryManager):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class UserCreator : MonoBehaviour
{

public static PersonModel CreateUser(PersonModel model)
{
    CountryModel nativeCountry = new CountryModel();
    nativeCountry = MySQLCountryManager.GetCountryByName(model.NativeCountry);
    <some other code here....>
}
}
```

And here is MySQLCountryManager class with GetCountryByName method:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class MySQLCountryManager : MonoBehaviour
{
public static CountryModel GetCountryByName(string countryName)
{
    CountryModel country = new CountryModel();
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("CountryName", countryName);
    UnityWebRequestAsyncOperation getCountryByName = new UnityWebRequestAsyncOperation();
    getCountryByName = UnityWebRequest.Post(WebReguests.getCountryByName, form).SendWebRequest();
    List<string> results = new List<string>();
    if (getCountryByName.webRequest.isNetworkError || getCountryByName.webRequest.isHttpError)
    {
        Debug.LogError(getCountryByName.webRequest.error);
    }
    else
    {
        var data = getCountryByName.webRequest.downloadHandler.text;
        string[] result = data.Split(',');
        for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
        {
            results.Add(result[i]);
        }
        int id;
        bool idOk;
        idOk = int.TryParse(results[0], out id );
        if (idOk)
        {
            country.id = id;
        }
        
        country.CountryName = results[1];
        
        byte[] flagBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(results[2]);
        country.Flag = flagBytes;
        byte[] shapeBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(results[3]);
        country.Shape = shapeBytes;
        byte[] woP = Convert.FromBase64String(results[4]);
        country.WorldPosition = woP;
        byte[] coa = Convert.FromBase64String(results[5]);
        country.CoatOfArms = coa;
        byte[] dishPicBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(results[6]);
        country.DishPic = dishPicBytes;
        byte[] curiosityBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(results[7]);
        country.CuriosityPic = curiosityBytes;
        country.Continent = results[8];
        country.Population = results[9];
        country.Capital = results[10];
        country.Language = results[11];
        country.Currency = results[12];
        country.Religion = results[13];
        country.DishName = results[14];
    }
    return country;
}
```

Now, the problem is, when I start debugging project in Visual Studio 2019 if I go Step Into on native country in UserCreator and then Step Into in MySQLCountryManager.GetCountryById, code works fine and returns nativeCountry as I expect. But when I go Step Over nativeCountry, it always throws some exceptions, like 'Index was out of range', 'Input string is not in a correct format' etc. And this is happening for all methods with UnityWebRequest called from UserCreator class.
I tried to google for this but nothing useful was found.
Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: Sounds like a race condition to me!

While stepping into the method you most probably give the asynchronous request just enough time to actually finish in the background.

I don't see where you are waiting for the results of the asynchronous download.

---

See the examples of [UnityWebRequest.Post](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Post.html) => as with any other asynchronous execution you have to wait until the results are actually back.

Usually you would use a Coroutine with callback like e.g.

```
public static void GetCountryByNameAsync(MonoBehaviour caller, string countryName, Action<CountryModel> whenDone)
{
    caller.StartCoroutine(GetCountryByNameRoutine(countryName, whenDone))
}

private static IEnumerator GetCountryByNameRoutine(string countryName, Action<CountryModel> whenDone)
{
    var form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("CountryName", countryName);

    using(var request = UnityWebRequest.Post(WebReguests.getCountryByName, form))
    {
        // WAIT until the request has either failed or succeeded
        yield return request.SendWebRequest();

        if (request.isNetworkError || request.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.LogError(request.error);
            yield break;
        }

        var data = request.downloadHandler.text;
        var results = data.Split(',');

        var country = new CountryModel();

        if (int.TryParse(results[0], out var id))
        {
            country.id = id;
        }
    
        country.CountryName = results[1];
    
        var flagBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(results[2]);
        country.Flag = flagBytes;
        var  shapeBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(results[3]);
        country.Shape = shapeBytes;
        var woP = Convert.FromBase64String(results[4]);
        country.WorldPosition = woP;
        var coa = Convert.FromBase64String(results[5]);
        country.CoatOfArms = coa;
        var dishPicBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(results[6]);
        country.DishPic = dishPicBytes;
        var curiosityBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(results[7]);
        country.CuriosityPic = curiosityBytes;
        country.Continent = results[8];
        country.Population = results[9];
        country.Capital = results[10];
        country.Language = results[11];
        country.Currency = results[12];
        country.Religion = results[13];
        country.DishName = results[14];

        whenDone?.Invoke(country);
    }
}
```

then later you would rather use it like e.g.

```
// caller will be whatever script is actually calling this method
// we will take that reference to make it also responsible for executing the according Coroutine
public static void CreateUserAsync(MonoBehaviour caller, PersonModel model, Action<PersonModel> whenDone)
{
    MySQLCountryManager.GetCountryByName(caller, model.NativeCountry, nativeCountry =>
    {
        <some other code here....>

        whenDone?.Invoke(theCreatedPersonModel);
    });
}
```

Or if it gets more complex instead of Coroutines you might rather use an `async` - `await` approach and pass the final result back into the Unity main thread.

Comment: Ok, thanks for answer, and sorry but I have to ask another question, in CreateUser, how to get nativeCountry as instance of CountryModel class with public properties?

Comment: `nativeCountry` is the instance of `CountryModel` that was passed into the callback action when calling `whenDone?.Invoke(country);` in `GetCountryByNameRoutine`

Comment: Yes, but what I'am trying to achive here is to create PersonModel in CreateUser class. PersonModel has public properties like id, NickName, VisitedCountries (List<CountryModel> in which goes nativeCountry on the begging of the game), etc. nativeCountry is just one step in creation of PersonModel, and I need to get it from another class (MySQLCountryManager). With your aproach I cannot call that method since it is in another class and has to be public static, and if it is public static, it cannot call Coroutine.

Comment: **why** does it need to be `static` though? Just make it instanced and get a reference to your `MySQLCountryManager` instance from your scene ... or in general you need just **any** `MonoBehaviour` reference so you could call `StartCoroutine` on it instead

Comment: I'am not familiar with this, cannot handle...appreciete if you can write me how to achive in UserCreator to have nativeCountry = ...     If not, thanks for answers anyway, sorry for disturbing.

Comment: I see you edited answer, but I still dont get it, sorry. Let me put this way, did not mentioned before, sorry. I have class UserOnStartHandler in that class I have method ConfirmButton(Button btn) from where I call  model =  UserCreator.CreateUser(model);           Idea is to create model in CreateUser method by assigning its properties, so I need nativeCountry = ..., so I can assign it to model.VisitedCountries. If you just explain to me how can I get nativeCountry = ... from Coroutine which is in another class (MySQLCountryManager), I would do all rest public properties the same way. Thanks!

Comment: @castelum85 please add all relevant code to your question! Does your `MySQLCountryManager` and `UserCreator` have to be a `MonoBehaviour` at all? currently it is hard to tell what exactly you need to achieve ... what I can tell you is this: Your main issue is that you don't wait until the asynchronous webrequest has finished

Comment: Ok, I have reorganized code, and now everything in one class UserOnStartHandler.cs. Now in Start() method I have method called HandleUserOnLoad, and in that method I have dropDown.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate{SelectNativeCountry(dropDown); });     In SelectNativeCountry I have  confirmButton.onClick.AddListener(delegate { ConfirmButton(confirmButton); });               In ConfirmButton(confirmButton) I have CreateUser() from where I call StartCoroutine(GetNativeCountryCoroutine()). The problem is, when yield return request.SendWebRequest(), nothing happens, I never get data.

Comment: After yield return request.SendWebRequest() it just skip everything after in code and returns to method from which coroutine is called. Script is attached to MainCamera, so object is never destroyed. Why is that happening, anyone?